VS2022 (ver 17.11.0) C++ constexpr bug?
Playing with constexpr I had a strange situation that I reduced to a simple C++ example that works fine on VS2019 and GCC (tested on godbolt.org) but fails on the latest VS2022 (ver 17.11.0)
constexpr bool contains(const char strz[], char ch) noexcept {//search a char in a 0-terminated string
    for(auto*c=strz; *c; ++c){
        if(*c == ch){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

struct S{
    static constexpr const char* const arr[] = {
        "abc",
        "*12"  // <-- comment this to get a compile error on VS2022
    };
};

template<typename S>
class Cls{
public:
    static constexpr auto func() noexcept {
        for(const auto& s: S::arr){
            if(contains(s, '*')){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
};

int main(){
    constexpr auto r = Cls<S>::func();// <-- remove constexpr to have it work also with only 1 element in "arr"
    return r;
}

The error is: error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
main.cpp(31,22): error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant
2>    C:\Prj\Test\src\main.cpp(31,22):
2>    failure was caused by unevaluable pointer value
2>    C:\Prj\Test\src\main.cpp(31,22):
2>    the call stack of the evaluation (the oldest call first) is
2>        C:\Prj\Test\src\main.cpp(31,36):
2>        while evaluating function 'bool Cls<S>::func(void) noexcept'
2>        C:\Prj\Test\src\main.cpp(22,24):
2>        while evaluating function 'bool contains(const char [],char) noexcept'

It is also very strange (to me) that it fails when the array "arr" has only one element but works when it has more!
Looks like it is constexpr-related because it works also after removing "constexpr" from main(), even in the case with only one element in "arr"
NOTE: the issue doesn’t appear with “arr” out of the struct or if I explicitly declare the array size
Did I missed something? Or there is a bug in the latest VS2022?
Can somebody please confirm/infirm the results I have with VS2022 (ver 17.11.0)?
EDIT: after confirmation from stackoverflow members I created a ticket:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-ver-17110-C-constexpr-bug/10725257
EDIT 2024-08-22: Microsoft: "A fix for this issue has been internally implemented and is being prepared for release. We’ll update you once it becomes available for download"
CLARIFICATIONS:

godbolt.org doesn't have any version of VS2022; latest there is a VS2019
on my computer I have latest available today (I checked before asking): VS2022 ver 17.11.0





Cannot reproduce with latest (see demo). Maybe it's a bug in a specific version.

Works here. So it seems to be already fixed.

"(tested on godbolt.org)..." Always use latest(trunk) version of the compilers. Especially when you're already using godbolt. The bug may already be fixed in the latest versions.

ver 17.11.0 of compiler iscertainly not latest. that's something from 2015. current are like 19.30s-19.40s

Compiles OK here on 17.1.0. So is may well be a new quirk.

My compiler identifies itself as Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
Version 17.1.0 VisualStudio.17.Release/17.1.0+32210.238 Installed Version: Community
Visual C++ 2022   00482-90000-00000-AA383
Microsoft Visual C++ 2022
Intel® C++ Compiler   2024.1

@Swift-FridayPie there's a difference between VisualStudio IDE version (current VS 2022 is 17....), and MSVC compiler (current is 19....).

@wohlstad yea, and IDE is quite irrlevant,..I'm using 19.x versions with 2017 IDE.. Oh, wait, maybe what OP expiriences is NOT message from compiler but from outdated or buggy  IntelliSense?

@Swift-FridayPie not sure what the OP exprience. I just meant that they seem to quote the IDE version, and this means that is not an old one from 2015 (as you commented), but the current one. I still cannot reproduce it with the latest MSVC.

The "latest" on godbolt might in fact not be the latest, as the last VS update is from "patch-Tuesday" last week. With compiler 19.41 (IDE 17.11.0) I get this error too. The message is "failure was caused by unevaluable pointer value", whatever that means.

@BoP where on earth you see 19.41 on godbolt? lates is 19.40 (VS 17.10). the 19.latest on godbolt fails to launch

Compiler version and VS version are ortognal. Compiler version doesn't appear in About dialog. It matters what "Platform Toolset" is used in project. and IDE can use any toolset regestered in OS correctly

@Swift - I'm not running on godbolt, I have Visual Studio on my computer, updated last week. Just saying that godbolt doesn't always update immediately, so their latest might be second-to-last when there is a brand new version out.

Please put the entire log message in the question.

I can reproduce the problem in Version 17.12.0 Preview 1.0
There is similar  constexpr  error report on developer community.
You can report the problem and post link here so that we can follow up.
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-C2131-on-calling-constexpr-functio/10722313?q=constexpr+C2131

@Minxin Yu - MSFT : I edit the OP to include the link:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-ver-17110-C-constexpr-bug/10725257

Had me confused for a minute, there. The Visual C++ compiler version does NOT appear in the Help >> About Microsoft Visual Studio dialog box. You can, however, check it in a program, by using the macros _MSC_VER, _MSC_FULL_VER, and _MSC_BUILD. See this Microsoft Learn article. After updating last week, the compiler version on my system now comes up as: _MSC_FULL_VER 194134120. That's version 19.41, build version 34120, revision version 0. _MSC_BUILD gives the revision version.

For me, the program crashes with the one-element array regardless of whether I remove constexpr in function main or not. Without constexpr (in both Debug and Release modes), it throws an exception at runtime: "Exception thrown: read access violation. c was nullptr." The offending line is line 2: for (auto* c = strz; *c; ++c).... The two-element array runs in both cases, and exits with code 1 (0x1). Does that indicate that constexpr might not be the problem?

@tbxfreeware indeed crashes after removing 'constexpr' from main() ... before I just stopped at compiling ... thanks for the findings!
It looks like when the array has one element (my intention) the compiler considers it as an array of 4 elements with the last 3 element NULL (as seen while debugging) for some reason (coincidence that the sizeof("abc") is 4 ?)
When the array has 2 elements then the compiler considers it also an array of 2 elements (as expected)

Here is another data point: When I added a set of braces around the initializers in struct S, then the program worked with a one-element array. So, arr[] = { {"abc"} }; worked, both with, and without, constexpr in function main. Looks like this problem is about the initializers, rather than constexpr.

@tbxfreeware OK, good to know... it is about initialization but in a wider context because it works fine when the array is not a static structure member but a static global. I expect some consistency but obviously it is missing in this case

Thanks for Solo's issue report.
The problem  has been internally fixed.
Developer community:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-ver-17110-C-constexpr-bug/10725257

VS2022 17.11.2 is out but the bug is still there! I suppose @Minxin Yu - MSFT wanted to write "the problem has been internally fixed"

Thanks. In addition, Visual Studio also has a preview version, currently VS 17.12.0 preview 1.0. You may need to wait for version 2.0 or later.
